# Haskell data type list

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell, and I want to make a program with lists. I want to read from keyboard next element, and append everything to my existing list. Because I used data types, I don't know how to add a new car with all those details, in my list named `cars`. 
  I know that sequence `let ls = name:model:color:year:price:coin:[cars]` is wrong and I have no ideea how to make it work. Can anyone give me an ideea about what can I do here please?

```
type Name = String
type Model = String
type Color= String
type Year = String
type Price = String
type Coin = String
data Car = Car String String String String String String deriving (Show)
cars :: [Car]
cars = [Car "Range Rover" "Sport Supercharged" "Blue" "2015" "85790" "$" ,  Car "BMW" "4-Series" "Black" "2014" "65489" "$"]

main = do
    putStrLn "Car details "
    putStr "Name: "
    name <- getLine
    putStr "Model: "
    model <- getLine
    putStr "Color: "
    color <- getLine
    putStr "Year: "
    year <- getLine
    putStr "Price: "
    price <- getLine
    putStr "Coin: "
    coin <- getLine
    let ls = name:model:color:year:price:coin:[cars]
    putStrLn (show ls)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First I'd recommend you actually *use* those type synonyms, if you define them at all:

```
data Car = Car Name Model Color Year Price Coin
  deriving (Show)
```

Note that this is completely equivalent to declaring all fields `String` (because `Model` and `String` are just different names for exactly the same type), it's just clearer to read. Even clearer might be if you used [record fields](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching#Introduction_to_records) for such a type, but that wouldn't make a difference here.

Now to “create” a new car from some string properties, you want to *not* concatenate these properties to a list. Instead, just use the `Car` constructor and prepend *a single car* to the list.

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Car details "
    putStr "Name: "
    name <- getLine
    ...
    let cars' = Car name model color year price coin : cars
    print cars'
```

In case you wonder: `Car foo bar baz : cars` is the same as `(Car foo bar baz) : (cars)`. In fact, `Car` is just used like any other function here; you could also define a helper function

```
redCar :: Name -> Model -> Year -> Price -> Coin -> Car
redCar n m y p c = Car n m "red" y p c
```

and then write

```
   print $ redCar name model year price coin : cars
```

OTOH, `[cars]` is *not* a list of cars that you could prepend another car to; rather it's a list *with a single element* (and that element is a list of cars).

A different subject is how you *update* stuff in general, in Haskell. ErikR adresses how this can be done with recursion; I'd note that you *can* also have proper mutable variables in Haskell IO code. We generally avoid working in IO as much as possible, but if you actually write an interactive application then it's sensible enough:

```
import Data.IORef

main = do
    knownCars <- newIORef cars
    putStrLn "Car details "
    ...
    modifyIORef knownCars $ Car name model color year price coin
    print =<< readIORef cars
```

Then you can follow this with

```
    putStrLn "Details of another car:"
    ...
    modifyIORef knownCars $ Car name2 model2 color2 year2 price2 coin2
```

and actually have both cars added. Of course this only makes sense if the whole program is actually running in a loop. (“Loop” still meaning recursion, in fact.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did my main, like you said in first `main` and now my program enters into a kind of infinite loop , and prints elements that have been read from the keyboard :D.

Comment: @ClaudiuM: I had a mistake in my original version, wrote `cars = ... : cars`, which defines in fact an infinite list. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

As you probably have been told, Haskell "variables" are not mutable. That means you have to explicitly pass state around as a parameter in your loop.

For example, this is a loop which will repeatedly ask the user for a color:

```
loop1 = do putStrLn "Enter a color: "
           color <- getLine
           loop1
```

However, the users's input is not "saved" anywhere. The next step is to keep track of all of previous input as a parameter to the looping function:

```
loop2 colors = do putStrLn $ "Previous colors: " ++ show colors
                  putStrLn "Enter a color: "
                  color <- getLine
                  loop2 (color:colors)
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Hello! , thank you for your suggestion. Because for and while does not exist here, I have wondered how loops look like here, in Haskell, and now I got it, because of you :D. Also, I found an answer for my original question (above answer) .